# How to write multiple sheets into a new excel, without overwriting each other?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to write multiple excels' column A into a new excel's column A (assuming all the excels have one worksheet each.) I've written some code, which can write one excel's column A into the new excel's column A; but if there are multiple excels, the new excel's column A will be overwritten multiple times. So how could I just add all the column As to the new excel sheet one after another without overwriting each other?
Below are my code:

```
import os, openpyxl

path = os.getcwd()

def func(file):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
            sheet = wb.active
            colA = sheet['A']
            wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
            r = 1
            for i in colA:
                sheet = wb.active       
                sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value = i.value
                r += 1
                wb.save('new.xlsx')
func(file)
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: You're overwriting the `file` parameter every time you call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could proceed for example as:

```
import os, openpyxl

path = os.getcwd()


def func(outputFile):
    c = 0

    #create output workbook
    wbOut = openpyxl.Workbook()
    sheetOut = wbOut.active

    for fName in os.listdir(path):
        if fName.endswith('.xlsx'):
            c += 1 #move to the next column in output

            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fName)
            sheet = wb.active #input sheet

            #for r in range(1, sheet.max_row+1):
            #    sheetOut.cell(row=r, column=c).value = sheet.cell(row = r, column = 1).value

            for r, cell in enumerate(sheet['A']):
                sheetOut.cell(row = r+1, column = c).value = cell.value

    wbOut.save(outputFile)

#"concatenate" all columns A into one single column
def funcAppend(outputFile):
    wbOut = openpyxl.Workbook()
    sheetOut = wbOut.active

    r = 1
    for fName in os.listdir(path):
        if fName.endswith('.xlsx'):
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fName)
            sheet = wb.active

            for cell in sheet['A']:
                sheetOut.cell(row = r, column = 1).value = cell.value
                r += 1
    wbOut.save(outputFile)

func('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: There is no need to use `sheet.max_row` or `range` for that matter, a simple enumerator will do.

Comment: @CharlieClark thanks, I have updated the answer - somehow the syntax `sheet['A']` didn't work for me until I upgraded openpyxl

Comment: You can also use an enumerator for your column counter.

Comment: Thank you @ewcz! It worked as the excels will be written to different columns. That's good! Is it possible to have them all written to column A? like you can append texts to a file to eliminate overwriting content. I'm thinking about doing that in excel column A actually.

Comment: @Penny the function `funcAppend` should do this - the difference is that the row counter `r` is common to all files and the output column is always set to 1

Comment: Hi @ewcz thank you so much!! It seems like where the `r=1` locates determines whether the excels content will append or overwrite. If the `r=1` is inside the for loop, then the content overwrite each other, but if it's outside the for loop, the content append each other. Would you mind help explain a little bit, as I'm still pretty green in writing scripts? :)

Comment: Hi @ewcz, actually there's an issue with this script - the content gets duplicated in the later rows, if we combine multiple excels. Have you tested on your end? Like combining 3 excels?

Comment: @Penny yes, I have tested it - the duplicated content might be because the output of the script `test.xlsx` is also stored in the current working directory so if you run the script twice, the content of `test.xlsx` is also loaded and thus appended to the other files yet again - try to delete it and use `func('/some/other/path/test.xlsx')`

Comment: Yes you're right @ewxz, I made a mistake of not deleting the generated xlsx. Thank you so much for all your help!!